# reactjs calculate sum of all the value present in state in a form of array of object

Tags: reactjs

[Codepen Reactjs][1]

```
`https://codepen.io/sushil6263/pen/NJXQKo`
```

How to calculate the sum of all the value present in the state in the form of an array of object. and when we delete an item total amount value need to be a change

Comment: Please update the question with example of the requrement

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum of object properties within an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27879827/218196)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope This helps

```
var accounts = [
      { name: 'James Brown', msgCount: 123 },
      { name: 'Stevie Wonder', msgCount: 22 },
      { name: 'Sly Stone', msgCount: 16 },
      { name: 'Otis Redding', msgCount: 300 }
    ];

// get sum of msgCount prop across all objects in array
var msgTotal = accounts.reduce((acc, cur) => (acc + cur.msgCount), 0);
```